# Do I need any sort of gdpr/cookie/localstorage notification if I only save data when the user creates an account?

Tags: legal, cookies, privacy, local-storage

I've made a website which is going into production soon. The website doesn't store any information about the user unless they create an account, in which case I save username, email and a password to a database, and a token in local-storage.

Do I need any sort of notification when the user navigates to the site?

Comment: This depends on the jurisdiction you are in, every single one of the jurisdictions that every single one of your users is in, possibly on the jurisdiction that your server is in, and in some convoluted cases maybe even some seemingly unrelated jurisdiction. This is a question that should be answered by a legal professional, not some random dude on the Interwebs, especially if that random dude is a Software Engineer, and thus very likely highly trained in Software Engineering, but not at all trained in the Law.

Comment: While legal questions are off topic here, if you are mostly interested in the GDPR do take a look at the law. In particular [article 13](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-13-gdpr/): “Where personal data […] are collected from the data subject, the controller shall, at the time when personal data are obtained, provide the data subject with all of the following information: […] the purposes of the processing for which the personal data are intended as well as the legal basis for the processing”. You then need to inform when the account is created, you don't have to display anything for normal visitors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The short answer is "Yes".

You'll have to check the full legal requirements, but basically if you are going to sell the users email on to marketing companies, that is 'a bad thing' and you should get their consent.

If you are *not* intending to do that kind of thing, then think about what assurance you can give the user that this will remain the case after elon musk offers you £££ for your website.

ie. you need to tell them why you want their email, say what you will use it for and promise to keep it safe from hackers.

Really you are better off not collecting it at all.